# Add temporary guest (Ephemeral user) to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need the following:

Regular User creates a Guest . This guest must have the ability to POST and GET from two Views.

I've created the following Guest Model:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, related_name='guests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    keys        = models.ManyToManyField(Key)
    email       = models.EmailField(blank=False)
    phone       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=10)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created     = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    state       = models.IntegerField(default=1,validators=[MaxValueValidator(1),MinValueValidator(0)])
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created']
```

This guest "user" is **a short-lived one** (After a few days is deleted) . I'd like to avoid having to create an User instance for each guest.

My approach would be to allow anonymous users on ViewA and ViewB, then, i'd check request['guest'] to get the guest's ID , retrieve it from database and compare request['headers'] token value.

As for permissions on DRF (Pseudo-code to get the idea)

class IsGuestActive(permissions.BasePermission):

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.is_anonymous() 
         guest_id =  request['guest']
         token    =  request['headers'].token
         return (Guest.objects.get(pk=guest_id, token=token) is not None)
```

I'm very new to Django, my main questions are:

1. is my approach viable?
2. Should i create an User with foreign key to Guest and use groups instead?

I really appreciate any tips on what's the best way to create Ephemeral users like i need to.

---

Edit (1)

Regarding safety, it really is dangerous using a duct tape type of solution, because no middleware would be responsible for authenticating a guest (Making the system prone to inadvertently giving permissions). But the approach of analyzing the headers within a permission class is not that unfeasible. From official documentation:

```
class BlocklistPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Global permission check for blocked IPs.
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ip_addr = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        blocked = Blocklist.objects.filter(ip_addr=ip_addr).exists()
        return not blocked
```

We can see here, that META is used to validate an access .
I'll need to dig further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, that i think is viable, to create a temporary controlled access to a View, without having to create a custom User:

Exclaimer: This method seems to be somewhat secure, considering the ephemeral nature of the guests using the system. It does not address the issue of controlling sessions, or retrieving access.

**The use-case:** You need a guest to access Views, but guest needs special authorization. This Guest will be short-lived.

**middleware.py**
Create a middleware where you define `request.guest = None`

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.guest = None
```

**models.py**
Now, we'll define our guest to have primary key as a token value:

```
class Guest(models.Model):
    reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation, related_name='guests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token       = models.CharField(max_length=40, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Meta:
    ordering = ['created']
    verbose_name = 'Guest'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Guests'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.token:
        self.token = self.generate_key()
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

def generate_key(self):
    return binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(20)).decode()

def __str__(self):
    return self.token
```

In my case, i send the guest a link with a token as a parameter.

As you don't want to store the token on localstorage or any other place that isn't an httpOnly cookie to avoid XSS attacks, define a View to respond to the first click of the link on the email:

```
class SetGuest(APIView):
    authentication_classes  = []
    permission_classes      = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, token, format=None):
        response                = HttpResponse("", status=308)
        response['Location']    = "http://localhost/index.html?redirect&action=confirm&status=success"
        response.set_cookie(key='guest_token', value=token, path='/', samesite='Lax', max_age=3600*24*7, secure=False, httponly=True)
        return response
```

This View will redirect your guest to a page, and set up the CSRF and guest_token cookie.

Define the decorator creating a **decorators.py**:

```
def validate_guest(view_func):
    def wrapper(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try: 
            token           = request.COOKIES.get('guest_token')
            request.guest   = Guest.objects.get(token=token)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.debug(str(e))            
            return redirect('/api/')

        return view_func(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

Now, to protect the view so it only works for guests with a token:

```
class GuestGetKeys(APIView):
    authentication_classes  = []
    permission_classes      = [IsGuest]
    dec_list                = [ensure_csrf_cookie]

    @validate_guest
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'status': 'valid', 'success': 'Guest is logged'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

One can achieve the same without using the decorator, but `permissions.py` instead.

The reason i prefer not to, is because through decorators i can control redirects in a cleaner way.

why defining the new dict value using a middleware? I tried modifying the request object directly on the Decorator and on the permissions class, it simply doesn't work.

There are a few short-comings from this approach, like session revoking issues, there's no other way of starting a "session" other than accessing the link sent to the guest, tokens are plain text and a database breach would allow anyone access as guests. Sessions don't expire, and so on.